# Overriding openAPI generated source

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator

I am using Spring boot with openAPI generator maven plugin and getting the source generated under src/main/java using the below config :

```
 <configuration>
            <inputSpec>openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
            <output>${project.basedir}</output>
            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
            <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
            <skipOverwrite>false</skipOverwrite>

            <modelNameSuffix>Dto</modelNameSuffix>
            <modelPackage>be.ordina.conference.api.model</modelPackage>
            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
            <generateModelDocumentation>true</generateModelDocumentation>

            <generateApis>false</generateApis>
            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>

            <library>jersey2</library>

            <configOptions>
                <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                <java8>true</java8>
                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                <sourceFolder>src/java</sourceFolder>
            </configOptions>
```

I want to modify generated Interface by changing few input parameter type,which i am doing under src/main/java.

Once the project is build again the changes are overridden by openAPI codegen.
I want to restrict that from happening.
Any pointers how to do that.

Comment: Ideally, the code inside `src/java` directory will be regenerated with the above configurations. Can you provide example on what kind of changes you are trying to make?

Comment: I want to modify the generated code inside src/java and want that during the next build the code modified by me doesn't gets re-generated  ,so basically i want to restrict the regeneration of a particular class/pojo in next successive builds.